# Handling name changes in active directory/exchange

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003

What is the correct procedure for changing someone's name and email address in an active directory 2003 with exchange environment?  For example when staff marries and their surname changes.  Both our usernames and email addresses are based on their name so it all changes.

Some specific issues I've run into are their old name showing up in exchange system manager, issues with their user profile not working properly on domain connected computers, and their old name still showing in the global address list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an FYI, if you rename *everything*, there may be some unexpected results.  One attribute in particular, legacyExchangeDN is known to cause issues.  Two issues that I know of are replying to old emails, and the Outlook "quick pick" list that may be used on the client when sending emails.

One might think that most people don't reply to old emails, but I was surprised how often this occurs.  For example, it may be a reply to a meeting request that was scheduled far in advance.

So if you *must* change legacyExchangeDN, you may want to consider setting up an Exchange object with the previous value to receive messages that target the old value, and have the messages actually delivered to the new mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

the Microsoft best practice for this is to create a new user, connect the "old" users mailbox and give the new user to the same security and distribution groups the "old" user was member. (your question is a question in ms exams too).

if you can't do that there is a way too. with adsiedit.msc you can change all AD attributes of the user.so you can rename the old to the new username completely.